# Is there a reason Germania aircraft cabins have blue lights?

Tags: cabin-design, aircraft-lighting

On my 2014-01-18 CET flight ST2114 from FKB to LPA on a [Germania airplane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germania_(airline)), cabin lights were switched from white to blue for takeoff. I recorded this in a [panoramic photo](https://theta360.com/s/bwA4qcgjMW8Y7vtfQh2uEyuA4).

Granted, on sunset, the sun coming in through the windows made up for a beautiful play of light: Blue and yellow are complementary colors.

*Is there a security or technical reason for the blue light, or is it just for
aesthetics?*

Comment: First thought on reading the title question was https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/to-your-health/wp/2018/06/29/the-plan-to-keep-drug-users-from-shooting-up-in-public-restrooms-and-why-it-may-be-a-bad-idea/    its probably unrelated though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Bergische Universität Wuppertal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Wuppertal) has done some research that chronobiologically-adapted LED lighting can enhance passengers well being and they can sleep better during a flight.

[This article](http://www.ledsmagazine.com/articles/2013/01/chronobiologically-adapted-led-lighting-improves-aircraft-cabin-environment.html) details about this research:

> Adaptive solid-state lighting (SSL) scenarios in which the color and
>   brightness of lighting is varied during long-distance overnight
>   flights results in passengers that sleep better and are more alert
>   upon arrival.
>
> ... at the start of an overnight flight that warm-white light helps to
>   stimulate melatonin production and increases passenger relaxation ...
>   blue-rich cold light in the morning increased alertness

There have been studies showing benefits of [biologically effective lighting for more relaxed flights](http://www.osram.com/osram_com/press/press-releases/_general_interest_press/2012/airbus/index.jsp).

Comment: +1 - Great answer and references, I remember reading a scientific article that mentioned night vision was no better or worse using red than any other color. Whatever color is used at night will diminish the eyes ability to see it for about 10min.